# PHP mkdir returns false but exec("mkdir") works

Tags: php, permissions, mkdir

I need to create a folder in PHP outside the web root.

The parent folder has 777 permissions.

If I call `mkdir($dir);` or `mkdir($dir, 0777, true);` it returns false and the folder isn't created.

However, if I call `exec("mkdir ".$dir);` the folder is created.

Is it normal?

Comment: Switch the errors on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php and let us know, what errors do you get?

Comment: Okay it says: `Wrong parameter count for mkdir()`. May the path contain a `/` at the end? I mean should I write `/myPath/` or `/myPath`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Older versions of php had different parameters for mkdir.

Try `mkdir($dir, permissions);`

Example:

```
mkdir($dir, 0777);
```

But I recommend updating the version of php